# What were all the Treasures of Thundera and their effects?

Tags: magical-items, thundercats

In one of the latter seasons of **Thundercats,** the planet of Thundera was magically reformed, and the over-arching arc was finding the "Treasures of Thundera." I remember some of them, such as:

- The *Book of Omens* which had prophetic powers and held "all the knowledge" of thundera, supposedly;
- a magical telescope of some kind;
- the *Totem of Dera,* which was supposedly "the most magical and ancient of the Thundercat treasures" and could heal anything ailment or injury, to the point of giving life to inanimate objects.
- A 2-fluked magical flute that could control all quadrupedal animals.

Does anyone know what the other treasures were, and what their abilities were? Are there any pictures there of?
And do these treasures appear in any of the various *Thundercat* comics?

Answer (score 4):

According to the (surprisingly accurate) [Thundercats wiki](https://thundercats.fandom.com/wiki/Treasure_of_Thundera), the known piece of treasure from Thundera were;

- **The Book of Omens**
- **The Key of Thundera**  (which appears to be used exclusively to open the Book of Omens)
- **The Double Headed Dragon of Doom** (used to protect the Book of Omens)
- **The Magical Flute** (which can control animals and Snarf)

> (All Seen in *TT: ThunderCubs*)

- **The Totem of Dera** (which appears to be able to resurrect the dead and control strong magic)

> Appears in *TT: The Totem of Dera*

- **The Chain of Loyalty** (which appears to have a positive effect on loyalty between Thunderian leaders)

> Appears in *TT: The Chain of Loyalty*

- **The Mirror of Truth**  (which only reflects the truth and can also deflect energy beams)

> Appears in *TT: Return of the ThunderCubs*

- **The Bracelet of Power**  (which appears to allow mind control of those who come within its vicinity).

> Appears in *TT: Bracelet of Power*